# reshape an index of dates to data frame of dates

Tags: r, date, reshape

I am doing some time series manipulations whereby I reshape some Date vectors into matrix elements for some further processing. But for some reason, I can't seem to re-apply the date class back inside either the matrix or data frame form.

let

```
idx <- as.Date(seq(20),format="%Y-%m-%d",origin="1970-01-01")
idx.m <- matrix(idx,nrow=5,ncol=4)
```

gives

```
  > idx.m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20
```

I convert to a data frame to hold the date objects.

```
idx.df <- data.frame(idx.m)
```

If I try some types of applies, I cannot seem to get back the date format.

```
> apply(idx.df,1,as.Date)
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
X1    1    2    3    4    5
X2    6    7    8    9   10
X3   11   12   13   14   15
X4   16   17   18   19   20
```

Even if the information was lost in the matrix translation, I should still be able to convert back to dates.

I've tried a few other ways, and I could swear I was able to do this in the past.
Is there some way to start out with an index vector as above, reshape it, and end up
with a dataframe (I don't think a matrix can hold dates, but characters) of dates maintaining the date property?

I could manually build the data frame this way

```
> idx.a <- idx[1:10]
> idx.b <- idx[11:20]
> data.frame(idx.a,idx.b)
        idx.a      idx.b
1  1970-01-02 1970-01-12
2  1970-01-03 1970-01-13
3  1970-01-04 1970-01-14
4  1970-01-05 1970-01-15
5  1970-01-06 1970-01-16
6  1970-01-07 1970-01-17
7  1970-01-08 1970-01-18
8  1970-01-09 1970-01-19
9  1970-01-10 1970-01-20
10 1970-01-11 1970-01-21
> class(data.frame(idx.a,idx.b))
[1] "data.frame"
> sapply(data.frame(idx.a,idx.b),class)
 idx.a  idx.b 
"Date" "Date"
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

- Maybe I should add that my intention is to do lots of matrix manipulations on reshaped data content, but I want to be able to retrieve corresponding (Date class) index values by row, column indexing later on.

Comment: ok, agreed. But is there a way to accomplish the above at least? 1) convert to matrix with numerical date elements 2) do all matrix manipulations 3) convert back to data frame of dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
idx <- as.Date(seq(20),format="%Y-%m-%d",origin="1970-01-01")
idx.m <- idx
dim(idx.m) <- c(5, 4)

is.matrix(idx.m)
## TRUE
```

You can get a cell, e.g. `id.m[2, 3]`, a column, e.g. `idx.m[, 2]`, etc. but not everything will work as expected.  `print(idx.m)` will print it out as if its a vector even though its a matrix and `as.data.frame.matrix(idx.m)` will convert it to a data frame but strip the `"Date"` class leaving numbers.

If you do want to convert it to a data frame you will have to work around the limitations:

```
DF <- as.data.frame.matrix(idx.m)
DF[] <- lapply(DF, as.Date, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

or

```
do.call(data.frame, split(idx.m, col(idx.m)))
```

Comment: Wow, that's something new for me.  +1

Comment: Interesting and also very compact +1. Often, I have vectors that when translated to rowXcol matrix sets, have remainders. I can't just do something like dim(idx.m) <- c(5,) without knowing the other value. I can do it in matrix(idx.m,ncol) form and get warnings().  I have to think about that more.

Comment: If its just a matter of not knowing the number of columns then try this: `dim(idx.m) <- c(5, length(idx.m) / 5)`

Comment: remainder returns an error, "Error: ...dims [product 24] do not match the length of object" Admittedly sloppy on the matrix[idx.m,ncol] format, but I only get warnings.

Comment: thanks for the nice alternatives as well. I really have to get more familiar with the [] <-  method, as it seems to solve a lot of these problems.

Comment: Your vector must have a length dividable by 5.  If not it needs to be padded out to such a length.  Suppose we have `idx19 <- idx[1:19]`.  Then: `idx.m <- c(idx19, rep(NA, 5 * ceiling(length(idx19) / 5) - length(idx19))); dim(idx.m) <- c(5, length(idx.m) / 5); class(idx.m) <- "Date"` .